# Wiring a bath fan/light fixture

Tags: wiring, bathroom, fans

I have a light fixture with a pull switch. I want to replace the light with a bath light/fan. I also need to    install and wire a switch for this fan. How do I do this?

Comment: Ronald, your question is quite broad in scope. Any basic home wiring guide ([for example](https://www.familyhandyman.com/electrical/wiring/how-to-roughin-electrical-wiring/)) would give you the general idea, and as a Q&A site we don't strive to reproduce such resources. You might revise to ask about any specific challenges you face. Be sure to include details about your fan and wiring.

Comment: Will you want a separate switch for light and fan?

Comment: If you're doing new wiring, decide what kind of fan you want first.  Light/vent; or Light/vent/heat; or Light/night-light/vent/heat, etc.  Those heavily impact what wires you need to run.  Also keep in mind that if you're adding a vent, you need to run a duct.

Comment: Changed plans, thank you for your answers.